# How to send json data in Java using HttpURLConnection and Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, httpurlconnection

when I use the following command line when trying to send a json request it works perfectly:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XGET '192.168.0.121:9200/shakespeare/_search?pretty' -d ' { "query" : { "match_phrase" : { "text_entry" : "to be or not to be" } } }'
```

So, now, and just for fun, I am trying to do the same using Java. So I have the following code extract:

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.121:9200/shakespeare/_search?pretty");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            
ObjectNode text = mapper.createObjectNode();
text.put("text_entry", "to be or not to be");
            
ObjectNode match = mapper.createObjectNode();
match.set("match_phrase",text);
            
ObjectNode query = mapper.createObjectNode();
query.set("query", match);
            
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.write(query.asText());
wr.flush();
            
System.out.println(query);
            
InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream))
           .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(result);
```

The output from Java code is completely different from the output from the curl command. As far as I could, query.asText() used in wr.write(query.asText()) is blank. so, it seems no query is sent to the server. but I've tried query.toString() or just query and I got nothing. Does anyone have any clue ?

Comment: Does `System.out.println(query);` print what you expect? Remember you can also have `System.out.println(query.asText());` if you want to see what it produces.

Comment: when I try `System.out.println(query);` it prints out what I expect. but when I try `System.out.println(query.asText());` I get nothing (blank output). Anyway, from the code above I got an answer from the server thats seems I am "querying" nothing: It seems I got all entries an not the ones who have "to be or not to be". When I am using curl command it works fine.

Comment: When I print `query.ltoString()`I got: `{"query":{"match_phrase":{"text_entry":"to be or not to be"}}}`, which seems ok. I tried:
`try(OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {    byte[] input = uery.toString().getBytes("utf-8");      os.write(input, 0, input.length); }` But I got error 406 from server. Ok, I will try to figure out this error, but anyway, I was not able to send a request to server as I did with curl command.

Comment: Ehm, sorry about the late reaction, but I think the problem mainly comes from that a [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request is normally not expected to have a body, see the "Note" explicitly pointing this out. With a `GET` you usually have a query string, the `?` thing at the end of the URL itself. Chances are that you should work towards a `POST` request instead (which `curl` also defaults to when providing data with `-d`, that's why you needed to use `-X`, which is always suspicious, as it's an override of the standard behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

Since it took me some undesirable time, I am putting the solution for future reference. I just had to set UTF-8 in Context-Type property: `connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");`, and use query.toString() when writing the String in OutputStream. Here is the entire code extract:

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.121:9200/shakespeare/_search?pretty");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            
            ObjectNode text = mapper.createObjectNode();
            text.put("text_entry", "to be or not to be");
            
            ObjectNode match = mapper.createObjectNode();
            match.set("match_phrase",text);
            
            ObjectNode query = mapper.createObjectNode();
            query.set("query", match);
            
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(query.toString());
            wr.flush();
            
            
            System.out.println(query.toString());
            
            
            InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
            
            String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream))
                       .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            System.out.println(result);
```